# Orchard Pager For Module Admin

Tags: orchardcms

so I've written a simple module, and I'm displaying a list of specific ContentItems through an AdminMenu. It all works fine with the exception of the Pager. The Pager is displaying the count for *all* ContentItems, and not the filtered list. I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing, but I can't quite figure it out.

Here is my Controller code:

```
    public ActionResult List(ListContentsViewModel model, PagerParameters pagerParameters) {
        var pager = new Pager(_siteService.GetSiteSettings(), pagerParameters);
        var query = _contentManager.Query<EventPart>(VersionOptions.Latest);

        switch (model.Options.OrderBy) {
            case ContentsOrder.Modified:
                query.OrderByDescending<CommonPartRecord>(cr => cr.ModifiedUtc);
                break;
            case ContentsOrder.Published:
                query.OrderByDescending<CommonPartRecord>(cr => cr.PublishedUtc);
                break;
            case ContentsOrder.Created:
                query.OrderByDescending<CommonPartRecord>(cr => cr.CreatedUtc);
                break;
        }

        var pagerShape = Shape.Pager(pager).TotalItemCount(query.Count());
        var pageOfContentItems = query.Slice(pager.GetStartIndex(), pager.PageSize).ToList();

        var list = Shape.List();
        list.AddRange(pageOfContentItems.Select(ci => _contentManager.BuildDisplay(ci, "SummaryAdmin")));

        dynamic viewModel = Shape.ViewModel()
                                 .ContentItems(list)
                                 .Pager(pagerShape)
                                 .Options(model.Options);

        // Casting to avoid invalid (under medium trust) reflection over the protected View method and force a static invocation.
        return View((object)viewModel);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I have a feeling it's likely to do with the `.Query<EventPart>`, but I haven't been able to figure out what else it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, for the sake of documentation; I was right when I commented that I thought it was to do with the `.Query<EventPart>`. I'm not sure of the logic behind it, but the query needed to be:

```
var query = _contentManager.Query<EventPart, EventPartRecord>(VersionOptions.Latest);
```

...with a reference to the *PartRecord*.

If anybody could provide comments on the logic behind it so I (and others reading this) can have a better understanding, that would be awesome!

Comment: If someone provides an explanation on the why and how of this Orchard magic, I'll accept their answer :)